# AndroidStudio erro OnClickListener()

Tags: android, android-studio, calendar

Não sei como corrigir o erro OnClickListener() na classe java abaixo, só tem ele para corrigir

Aqui o código completo para baixar:
https://www.sendspace.com/file/4sgv14

Erro:
[image: erro]

```
classe  OlaCalendario.java
package com.example.brainiac.olacalendario;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;

import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.icu.util.Calendar;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class OlaCalendarioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView mDateDisplay;
    private Button mPickDate;
    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;

static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;




protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ola_calendario);

    mDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay);
    mPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);

    mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    updateDisplay();
}

private void updateDisplay() {
    mDateDisplay.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based so add 1
             .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
             .append(mDay + 1).append("-")
             .append(mYear + 1).append(" "));
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener=
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                mYear = year;
                mMonth = month;
                mDay = dayOfMonth;
                updateDisplay();
            }
        };

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
    switch (id){
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this,mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    }
    return null;

    }
}
```

---

arquivo `ola_calendario.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pickDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Altere a Data "
        />
</LinearLayout>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido usei o Calendar do Java ao invés do Android

```
import java.util.Calendar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Parece que esse onClickListener está derivando de um classe que precisa implementar alguma coisa abstrada, então basta adicionar a classe View antes do onClickListener para chamar ele apartir dessa classe, da seguinte forma:

```
    mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
           showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });
```

Acho que irá funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

O metodo on click precisa esta implementado com o Override:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    onAcao();
}
```